# How to read view model property from mvc MVC t4 template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, code-generation, template-engine, t4

I have created view model class like below

```
public class GenericFormModel
    { 
        public string SimpleInput { get; set; } 
        public string InputAddOn { get; set; } 
        public string InputTextArea { get; set; } 
        public RSelectListItem DropdownInput { get; set; }  
    }
```

Then I try to access all the propery from my own custom t4 template CustomCreate.cs.t4 like bellow

```
<# 
foreach (PropertyMetadata property in ModelMetadata.Properties) {
if (property.Scaffold && !property.IsAutoGenerated && !property.IsReadOnly && !property.IsAssociation) {

if (property.IsPrimaryKey && IsPropertyGuid(property)) {
continue;
}

#> 
 <#=property.PropertyName#>  
<#
}
}
 #>
```

It give output like below

```
 SimpleInput 
  InputAddOn
  InputTextArea
```

It did not display `DropdownInput`, I need to read DropdownInput  property from my t4 template.

I am using VS 2013 with MVC 5.